# Dimension Mismatch in Transformer Decoder: What Are the Input and Output Dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transformers, attention

My understanding is that in the decoder, the output of the masked self-attention mechanism is expected to have dimensions (o_len,d_model), where o_len is the current output length.

[image: masked self-attention]

[image]
However, an issue arises when the keys (K) and values (V) used in the self-attention of the decoder are obtained from the output of the encoder. Their dimensions are (n, d_model), where n represents the number of embedding vectors. This poses a problem during the computation of Q x K^T because Q has size (o_len,dq), while K^T has a size of(d_model,n), and dq is not equal to dmodel.
​
[image]
[image]

[image]